# Unexpected margin occurs in responsive design

Tags: html, css

---

why is this unexpected margin occurs in some of the mobile views ??

for example: In iphone XR, this annoying white line appears at the right and below navbar
[image]

In portrait view of some other mobiles:

[image]

But in landscape view it appears exactly as it is expected:
[image]

this problem occurs when zoom in developer tools is small but when I do zoom 100%, the line disappears.

Below is my code for the same.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    
    overflow: auto;
}
:root {
    --headerBackgroundColor: #1B1B23;
    --headerTextColor: #fff;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Table of Contents
1. Navbar
2. Header
3. Steps




 */




/* ===============
    1. Navbar 
   ============= */
.navbar {
    background-color: var(--headerBackgroundColor);
}

.navbar__brand {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: var(--headerTextColor);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar>.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 29px;
    padding-bottom: 29px;
}

.navbar__menuIcon>svg {
    font-size: 10px;
}

/* ===============
    2. Header 
   ============= */
.header {
    background-color: var(--headerBackgroundColor);
    padding: 5vh 0 10vh 0;
}

section .container {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: var(--headerTextColor);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    font-size: 19px;
}

section .header__h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 42px;
}

.container .header__para {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    line-height: 27px;
}

.container .header__downloadNow svg {
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.container .header__downloadNow {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 183px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--headerBackgroundColor);
    background-color: #FFB703;
    margin-top: 43px;
}


/* ===============
    3. Steps
   ============= */
.steps {
    background-color: #FFF6E0;
}

.steps svg {
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">

            <a href="#" class="navbar__brand">Aseedo</a>
            <span class="navbar__menuIcon">
                <svg width="25" height="28" viewBox="0 0 40 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect width="40" height="4" fill="white" />
                    <rect y="12" width="40" height="4" fill="white" />
                    <rect y="24" width="40" height="4" fill="white" />
                </svg>
            </span>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="header">
        <div class="container">

            <h2 class="header__h2">Connect your nearby businesses and get instant discount</h2>
            <p class="header__para">Aseedo will help customers to connect them to nearby shops and get instant discount
                on every purchase.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="header__downloadNow">
                <svg width="26" height="28" viewBox="0 0 26 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="M0 1.71813V26.2806C0.000164555 26.3339 0.0160587 26.386 0.0456893 26.4303C0.07532 26.4746 0.117368 26.5091 0.166561 26.5296C0.215754 26.5501 0.269902 26.5556 0.322215 26.5455C0.374528 26.5353 0.422677 26.5099 0.460625 26.4725L13.25 14L0.460625 1.52625C0.422677 1.48884 0.374528 1.46346 0.322215 1.4533C0.269902 1.44314 0.215754 1.44865 0.166561 1.46915C0.117368 1.48964 0.07532 1.5242 0.0456893 1.56849C0.0160587 1.61278 0.000164555 1.66484 0 1.71813ZM18.6125 8.875L2.57625 0.0400032L2.56625 0.0343782C2.29 -0.115622 2.0275 0.258128 2.25375 0.475628L14.8244 12.4956L18.6125 8.875ZM2.255 27.5244C2.0275 27.7419 2.29 28.1156 2.5675 27.9656L2.5775 27.96L18.6125 19.125L14.8244 15.5031L2.255 27.5244ZM25.0862 12.4375L20.6081 9.97125L16.3975 14L20.6081 18.0269L25.0862 15.5625C26.3044 14.8894 26.3044 13.1106 25.0862 12.4375Z"
                        fill="#1B1B23" />
                </svg>
                Download App</a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="steps">
        <div class="container">
            <svg width="114" height="115" viewBox="0 0 114 115" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="64" cy="65" r="50" fill="#FFB703" />
                <text x="50" y="80" font-family="poppins" font-size="55" fill="black">1</text>
                <rect x="0.369629" y="33.8839" width="5" height="15.3037" rx="2.5"
                    transform="rotate(-75 0.369629 33.8839)" fill="#FFB703" />
                <rect x="0.189453" y="5.32471" width="5" height="29" rx="2.5" transform="rotate(-45 0.189453 5.32471)"
                    fill="#FFB703" />
                <rect x="26.6875" y="1.29694" width="5" height="17" rx="2.5" transform="rotate(-15 26.6875 1.29694)"
                    fill="#FFB703" />
            </svg>
            <p class="steps__para1">Sign up to the aseedo services for free</p>

        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't see anything worng with your code. It could be a Chrome inspector bug (it happens)... The bad is that you may need to check it in production with that mobile phone which it's not often easy to do. I had to bet I would say it would work fine.

Comment: I have checked it in my mobile phone (vivo z1 pro). In that the white line below the navbar is still visible however the right side line disappeared. This is the link for the website: https://curious-vacherin-327d3b.netlify.app/#